# Disabling features of rails application depending on roles/subscriptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, roles, subscriptions

are there any good gems/plugins/extensions for rails to disable features selectively for users depending on their roles or package subscriptions they have?

For example, two packages (standard, premium) exist. The standard package allows the user to ask up to 20 questions per month within the application, the premium package allows the user to ask 50 questions per month. So the feature restriction doesn't include the package subscription only but the amount of already asked questions too.

Note: I am already using [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/) for simple authorization tasks.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and stay within cancan if possible..  You're probably using devise for authentication already?  If so I would try and modift cancan.  If the basic case if that a user is either a superuser (sysadmin) or a premium_user or a standard_user you can have roles for those three things.

If a user can register for more than one thing I would look to either create a membership / product registration class (user_id, package_id, membership_level_id) or add scopes/conditions/flags to user to see who can do what starting from the 'what' first and then crossing to qualified user.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I already thought about that, but the problem is that I also need some more information why a user can not access a given feature/function within the application. So only to know that a standard user is not allowed to post another question is not enough, I would like to give some more details like an self-explaining exception message. Also there could be several reasons why a user can not post another question (i.e. subscription expired, too many questions, user is locked, etc.).   Any ideas how to realize this with cancan?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Rolify`. This is a good gem that integrates very well with `CanCan` for resource scoping and authorization.
Documentation tutorial on how to use the two of them together:
https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can define inheritable roles with cancan. This would allow you to create your two roles, standard and premium, and have premium inherit all of the abilities of standard and the define your own.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization